# Move an item to top of list with "shooting up" animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I'm looking for some way (javascript, jQuery, CSS3) to move a list item to the top of an unordered list when clicked and animate while doing it to show the item shooting up the list to its place at the top of the list.

Something a bit like this: http://www.sarasoueidan.com/demos/creative-list-effects but in reverse and using a set list of items like this:

Is this even possible?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
.value {
  cursor:pointer;
  position: relative;
}

<ul class="list">
  <li class="value">Value 1</li>
  <li class="value">Value 2</li>
  <li class="value">Value 3</li>
  <li class="value">Value 4</li>
  <li class="value">Value 5</li>
  <li class="value">Value 6</li>
  <li class="value">Value 7</li>
  <li class="value">Value 8</li>
  <li class="value">Value 9</li>
  <li class="value">Value 10</li>
</ul>

$(".value").on("click", function() {
  $(this).animate({
    opacity: 0.5,
    top: "-=200"
  //}, {
    //step: function (now, fx) {
      // if ($()) $(this).stop();

      // if(fx.prop === 'top' && Math.abs(now) >= Math.abs(parseInt($(".list").css("height"), 10))) {
      //   $(this).stop();
      // }
    //}
  }, 1000, function() {
    $(".list").prepend($(this));
    $(this).css("top", 0);
    $(this).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 500 );
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/779771/

It shoots the item up the screen, but I want it to settle into the top position, whereas now it keeps going. I thought adding a step where it stops when it gets to the height of the container, but it still shoots past it.

Comment: Please provide some type of code snippet of your attempt so far. This way I can improvise off of that.

Comment: and yes this is possible. you will need to write some JQuery functions to fire on click events for it to move. You can animate either through CSS3 animations or JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I need to set the minus top value to the offset of each list item, like so:

```
$(".value").on("click", function() {
  var position = $( this ).position();
  event.stopPropagation();

  $(this).animate({
    opacity: 0.5,
    top: "-="+position.top
  }, 800, function() {
    $(".list").prepend($(this));
    $(this).css("top", 0);
    $(this).animate({
      opacity: 1
    }, 500 );
  });
});
```

And remove the margins so it stops in the first position:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.list {
  margin: 0;
}
```